# Active Directory authentication without Login form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I want to authenticate my Users to Active Directory but without any login form and on button click.

I just want to open my default page if user logged in to machine belongs to Active Directory.

Here, I have used Forms Authenication.

Can anyone give me the idea to achieve the same?
Your suggestion would be appreciated....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net mvc you can use Identity 2 to validation of your user.
to add identity 2 you should open **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console**.
then write the following code in there:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

It will add some class and sample that you can delete samples in view.

In this below example you can define property in top of your controller to help you sign in:

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }
```

then every where in your controller you can use this class(`SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe);` to login. in this class the third param is a `bool` that show you if you want keep signing in or not.

after user login to your page, in your page that you want limit to authenticated user you can add `[Authorize]` Annotation up to your controller then only authenticated users have allow to access.
for example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

if anything missed tell me.

Comment: thanks for the answer.....but I used principal context method